# How to make one element span the whole cell in React Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi I want to make my td element tag occupy the whole cell belongs to that column. This the output I got so far:[image]

Basically, I want the "Independent Study" to occupy the first column.
This is my code so far:

```
                   <Table striped bordered hover>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{`Courses Taught By ${this.state.professorname}`}</th>
                                <th>{`Comments on Course`}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tr>
                            {this.state.courses.map((course, i) => (
                            <tr>
                                <td key={course._id}>
                                    <Link to={`/${this.state.id}/${course._id}`}>{course.name}</Link>
                                </td>
                                {this.state.comments[i].map((comment, j) => (
                                    <td key={j}>
                                        <p>{this.state.comments[i][j]}</p>
                                    </td>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    </Table>
```

I would really appreciate some help, since this one troubled me for so long. Thanks.

Comment: You have a tr inside the tr

Comment: I thought I need that in order to have nested map.

Comment: You don't need it. When you are looping through the comments, create a table inside the td. otherwise you will have a nested tr.

Comment: Hi buddy, would you mind show me the code on how to through the second map based on the previous map index? I tried it but failed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: added the code. I did not test it but you'll get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have a two columns table, but your logic is to not render the second column if there's no comment. All you need to do is to move the second  out of your map. That way you retain the table cell if it's empty. You also nested tr > tr which is invalid, I changed the wrapping tr to tbody. Lastly, the key should be on the tr for the row, not on the first column's td. Hope this helps.

```
<Table striped bordered hover>
         <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>{`Courses Taught By ${this.state.professorname}`}</th>
                   <th>{`Comments on Course`}</th>
               </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
               {this.state.courses.map((course, i) => (
                   <tr key={course._id}>
                        <td>
                             <Link to={`/${this.state.id}/${course._id}`}>{course.name</Link>                  
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        {this.state.comments[i].map((comment, j) => (
                             <p key={j}>{this.state.comments[i][j]}</p>
                        ))}
                        </td>
                   </tr>
                ))}
         </tbody>
    </Table>
```

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks a lot! It worked greatly. Appreciate it,

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the nested tr

```
<Table striped bordered hover>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{`Courses Taught By ${this.state.professorname}`}</th>
            <th>{`Comments on Course`}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        {this.state.courses.map((course, i) => (
            <tr>
                <td key={course._id}>
                    <Link to={`/${this.state.id}/${course._id}`}>{course.name}</Link>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            {this.state.comments[i].map((comment, j) => (
                                <td key={j}>
                                    <p>{this.state.comments[i][j]}</p>
                                </td>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         ))}
     </tr>
 </Table>
```

There are other options as well using a colspan or just add the comments into the td as p tags and style it in css
Here is the other solution using p tags:

replace this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        {this.state.comments[i].map((comment, j) => (
            <td key={j}>
                <p>{this.state.comments[i][j]}</p>
            </td>
         ))}
     </tr>
</table>
```

to this:

```
{this.state.comments[i].map((comment, j) => (
    <p key={j}>{this.state.comments[i][j]}</p>
))}
```

and just use css to style it

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you need to use the `colspan` attribute of the `td` element.

For example if you have the following structure:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Actions</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">John Doe</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The John Doe td would occupy the 2 columns the previous `td` elements create.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. However, the "independent study" cell just tries to occupy its own column. It did not try to span onto the second column.

Comment: Also, I did what you suggested ... nothing seemed to change.

Comment: Oh yes, it's as the other guys say, the extra `<tr>` didn't see that one. You could also add a `<tbody>` to have it a little more structured.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of extra **tr** inside the map loop.   I created one playground. **Code** :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      tableData : ["testing1","testing12"]

    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Test-1</th>
                  <th>Test-2</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {
            this.state.tableData.map(data => {
              return(
                <tr>
            <td>{data}</td>

          </tr>
              )
            })
          }
              </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

LIVE DEMO : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ueqvy6

Comment: Hi buddy, thank you so much. It is really helpful. However, how could you take account of the second map is based on the index of the first for loop?

Comment: Can you explain with an example. I didn't understand.